# adjusting css position of div box element

Tags: css

Here i have created box which shows user post,

Name, post don't align properly. Can someone point me where I have made mistake?

[Code pan link](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/lKGED)

If post is very small then `like comment` should appear atleast at height = picture size.

Comment: also...you have spelling error...it should `SPOT`, not `PSOT`!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the width of floated div, which is covering the entire div, thereby pushing `name` out of alignment

**Code**

```
 <div class="name" id="wall1" style="
           text-align:justify;
           float:left;
           border:1px solid #000;   /* to find the area covered*/
           white-space:nowrap;
           width:20%   /* markup to align name and fix the width*/
"> nice post<br />
```

since you have not mentioned the `width` of floated div, its taking the whole 100%, place a value to fix the `div width`

Comment: whats the alignment you need??? `POST` => `Name`  then on new line `time` => `comment` => `like`.....(this is your present view) u just want to shift them a bit left-right or change or change the view completely???

Comment: Name should be above POST.

Answer (score 1):

You should revise your html. i.e. `<label>` element should not be used outside of `<form>` element.
I don't know what are you trying to achieve but this might help:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/epomschar/pen/HqJmD)

Comment: @Blix9: you changed order and look. Actually I want show User post like we can see on social media. Name, post below name. like comment link below post.

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to sketch/show that it is better not to use in-line styling. An that the <label> tag should not be used in this case. Hope you got that sorted.